# Many to Many DAO

Tags: java, sqlite, many-to-many, dao

I have a question about many to many relation with DAO design.

I have an object `User` with a `userDAO` and an object `Interest`, with `InterestDAO`.

I have a many to many relationship between both, a user can have many interest and an interest can have many user.

My question is : Do I need to create a third object and a third DAO to do the junction table ? Or do I create a Collection of person in Interest, and a list of Interest in person ?

Thanks !